# Can I say ... “This quote is so accurate to them..”?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Is it possible to use this formulation?

> This quote is so accurate to them.

I'm trying to say it fits them just perfectly. Such as when something fits somebody like it was meant for them: e.g. It fits like ass on the pot!

Comment: Look up synonyms for apt, appropriate, suited.

Comment: If the question is whether you can say "accurate to" then it has been asked before: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/160768/can-you-say-accurate-to

Comment: You must have one customized pot.  I thought those things were pretty much one-size-fits-all.

Comment: @Jim I LOLed! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence "This quote is so accurate to them" sounds awkward, but it literally means this: *they* (whoever the "them" is referring to) would find the *meaning* of the quote to be accurate (i.e. correct and truthful). It doesn't come close to meaning what you want to convey.

I would suggest alternatives such as:

"This quote is so *descriptive* of them."

"This quote is so *appropriate* in *describing* (alternative: *characterising*) them."

"This quote is so *applicable* to them." (I acknowledge the other answer that has already mentioned this, but I wanted to include it for completeness).

You can also consider more idiomatic phrases like:

"This quote *fits them to a T*."

Answer (score 0):

You've got three problems with

> This quote is so accurate to them.

1. You'll mislead your reader into thinking about the accuracy of the quote, not it's applicability.  An accurate quote is one that faithfully records the speaker's words, which could be the case without the quote being meaningful in context
2. You can use "accurate to," but it's usually involves a standard of comparison:

> The watch is accurate to the second.

3. You need some word to convey the importance of the sentiments of the quote, not the fact that it's a quote.  Perhaps

> This quote is so applicable to them.
>   This quote characterizes them.
>   The sentiments of this quote fit them perfectly.